# Python - How to get values of subkeys in registry

Tags: python, registry, winreg

I've got a little issue with getting the values of subkeys in Windows registry.
Suppose I've got this key: 
{49B2791A-B1AE-4C90-9B8E-E860BA07F889} and I want to get his subkeys values,
Currently after running my code I only managed to get the first subkey value, but I want to get all the values of all the children. 
I think I have issues with the indexes.

```
import winreg 

def reg_read(key):
    try:
        # storing key object
        hKey = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, key)
        counter = 0
        while counter < 4 :
            # Getting child keys from parent key as str type.
            sub_key = winreg.EnumKey(hKey,counter)
            # Constructing a new key full path. 
            sub_key_full_name = key + sub_key
            # Storing child key object.   
            hSubkey = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, sub_key_full_name) 
            # getting child values.
            key_name, key_value, key_type = winreg.EnumValue(hSubkey,counter)
            print("Value is:" + key_value)
            counter += 1                        


    except WindowsError as err:
        print(err)  
        pass                

# Parent key 
key = 'CLSID\{49B2791A-B1AE-4C90-9B8E-E860BA07F889}\\'
reg_read(key)
```

If could someone point me on my mistakes here or come up with different approach to this thing  I will be grateful. I'm new to programming and to Python as well.
It's my first question here in stackoverflow so thanks and hello!

Comment: Why do you quote only last backslash?